# What counts as "humanoid" for the target of the Enlarge Person spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, targeting

I know that [similar versions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/108741/how-can-non-humanoids-benefit-from-enlarge-person) of this question have been asked, even by me.

The line in question of the [*enlarge person*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enlarge-person/) spell says:

> **Target** one humanoid creature

The [glossary/common terms](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary) doesn't include this term. Nor does the spell itself state what a humanoid creature is. Is it a creature in a similar shape as a human, or possessing the humanoid [subtype](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types/)?

I ask because [earth elementals](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/elemental/elemental-earth/) are described as:

> This hulking, **roughly humanoid creature** of dirt and stone explodes up from the earth, faceless save for two glowing gemstone eyes.

Thus, an earth elemental ***is*** humanoid in form but not type. Does the spell work on things with head(s), arm(s), leg(s), and a torso?

Comment: Related: [Does a Monstrous Humanoid or a Fey count as Humanoid for armor costs and spell effects?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/84808)

Answer (score 8):

*Enlarge person* refers to the [Humanoid creature type](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/Creature-types/#TOC-Humanoid). Only creatures of that type can be targeted with that spell.<sup>1</sup> Creatures of any other type—aberration, animal, construct, dragon, fey, monstrous humanoid, ooze, outsider, plant, undead, or vermin—are not eligible for that spell. This would include earth elementals, as they are outsiders, not humanoids. Being “roughly humanoid in shape,” even being *perfectly* humanoid in shape (as, for example, a doppelganger might well be), is not relevant—only the creature type is.

1. <sub>Barring special cases like the spell sharing of animal companions</sub>

Comment: So, the answer is RAI because no where does it state its the subtype?

Comment: @Fering “RAI” does not mean “not-rules-as-written.” Please do not use it that way; it only fosters confusion and miscommunication. There is no claim whatsoever that anything is RAI, and if there was, that would be backed up with a statement indicating intent by one of Pathfinder’s authors, which is conspicuously absent. Anyway, no, this is purely RAW—this is what the term “humanoid creature” means in Pathfinder. The “roughly” qualifier for earth elementals—not to mention the indication of its outsider type—makes that a complete red herring.

Comment: @Fering It’s unfortunate that Pathfinder often uses game terms in their regular-English sense without any particular indication of that, but ultimately context will make things clear in almost all cases. Both *enlarge person* and the description of earth elementals are very much in the category of “clear cases.”